# How to extract map from json string

Tags: json, jqgrid

I need help to create a map from a json string.

I have a jqgrid in the jsp from which I am passing a JSON string to the controller for parsing.

My string looks like

```
[{"entityID":"1","entity":"Test","hierLevel":"Organization","access":"False"},
 {"entityID":"2","entity":"Test1","hierLevel":"Organization","access":"True"}]
```

In the server side, I want to extract a map from it with key as entityID and value as access which is a boolean.

Comment: I feel like there's extraneous info in this question, and the important stuff is missing...Are you saying you have a string of JSON and wish to deserialize it in JSP, then reorganize it into a map in the form of "entityID Value" => "access Value"?

Comment: In the JSP, I have a jqgrid with the above mentioned 4 columns; I want to pass these info to the controller from where I will call the service method to insert into database.

I am pretty new to Jqgrid and upon reference I found that we can use jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('getRowData') to find the rowdetails. Post this it converts it to string using JSON.stringigy().
Now I need to convert thr string to map with only the first and the last pair.

I hope it stands clear now.

Comment: It is a little more clear. Some of my confusion is that I am unfamiliar with the JSP world. That said, all the jQuery and plugin info is what I'm saying is extraneous. No one who can help you de-serialize the JSON and reformat the structure needs to know anything about where it's coming from or why--just that you have JSON, what that JSON looks like, what you want to end up with, and what platform your server/controller is.

Comment: Okay! I get the concern. Let me put it point wise. 

1. Form the front end I need to pass the values user has entered which I am able to do it as mentioned in the first comment. 
2. Now I want to pass values to the server and create a java hashmap with key as "entityID" and value as "access". The controller receives a String similar to what I have mentioned in the question. Based on this string, I need to parse it and make a map out of it which I will eventually pass to the service method.